# How to see a list of available filesystems that I can use for the mkfs command?

Tags: linux, filesystems, command-line-arguments

Simply I would like to create some FAT filesystem. I would like to know what kind of FAT filesystems are available and what are their names. How can I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

If this is output intended to be read by a human, then simply:

```
% man mkfs.fat
```

or

```
% man mkdosfs
```

These are in Section 8, a section of the Linux Programmer's Manual. Section 8 covers administration and privileged commands. This assumes you have the appropriate package containing this manual page installed.

It should mention FAT12, FAT16, and FAT32 for instance.

Comment: For more on the _kinds of FAT_ that the questioner asks about there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT_filesystem_and_Linux .

Answer (score 1):

There is short and incomplete list in `man mkfs` in see also section http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.8.html

> mkdosfs(8), mke2fs(8), mkfs.bfs(8),        mkfs.ext2(8), mkfs.ext3(8), mkfs.ext4(8), mkfs.minix(8),        mkfs.msdos(8), mkfs.vfat(8), mkfs.xfs(8)

And there is longer list in list of all standard Linux mans: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_alphabetic.html

```
mke2fs(8) - create an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem
mke2fs.conf(5) - Configuration file for mke2fs
....
mkfs(8) - build a Linux filesystem
mkfs.bfs(8) - make an SCO bfs filesystem
mkfs.btrfs(8) - create a btrfs filesystem
mkfs.cramfs(8) - make compressed ROM file system
mkfs.minix(8) - make a Minix filesystem
mkfs.xfs(8) - construct an XFS filesystem
```

Distribution will list much more mkfs's, there is ubuntu's list (search for mkfs): http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/

```
[TXT] jfs_mkfs.8.html       
[TXT] mkfs.8.html                                  
[TXT] mkfs.bfs.8.html                              
[TXT] mkfs.btrfs.8.html                            
[TXT] mkfs.exfat.8.html                            
[TXT] mkfs.ext2.8.html                             
[TXT] mkfs.ext3.8.html                             
[TXT] mkfs.ext4.8.html                             
[TXT] mkfs.ext4dev.8.html                          
[TXT] mkfs.f2fs.8.html                             
[TXT] mkfs.gfs2.8.html                             
[TXT] mkfs.hfs.8.html                              
[TXT] mkfs.hfsplus.8.html                          
[TXT] mkfs.jfs.8.html                              
[TXT] mkfs.logfs.8.html                            
[TXT] mkfs.lustre.8.html                           
[TXT] mkfs.minix.8.html                            
[TXT] mkfs.msdos.8.html                            
[TXT] mkfs.nilfs2.8.html                           
[TXT] mkfs.ntfs.8.html                             
[TXT] mkfs.ocfs2.8.html                            
[TXT] mkfs.reiser4.8.html                          
[TXT] mkfs.reiserfs.8.html                         
[TXT] mkfs.ufs.8.html                              
[TXT] mkfs.vfat.8.html                             
[TXT] mkfs.xfs.8.html       
[TXT] mkntfs.8.html                                    
[TXT] mkreiser4.8.html                             
[TXT] mkreiserfs.8.html
```

Not all tools will be installed by default. In Ubuntu you can try to run the tool, and if it is not installed, Ubuntu will give you hint about package name to install the tool.

Comment: You've missed the part where the questioner specified _what kind of **FAT** filesystems_.  JonathanS's answer (very briefly) addresses the _kinds of FAT_ filesystems.

Comment: Ok, my answer was to the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/filesystems | grep -v nodev
```

That will list all of the filesystems supported by your kernel that can be associated with physical disk devices.

Comment: It will list filesystems supported by kernel, no FUSE fs (?); and no information about fs formatting tools. ardabro may grep for files named like mkfs in /usr/bin and /usr/sbin.

Comment: Thanks. Looking into directory for programs mkfs* seems to be the best option.